# Oracle ADF Essentials 10.2.1 Task Flow Not Working

Tags: eclipse, oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

I have create a simple JSPX file and a Task Flow using Eclipse Neon OEPE 12.2.1.5

Task Flow XML `mainTab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<adfc-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller/adfc-config_1_0.xsd">
    <task-flow-definition id="mainTab">
        <default-activity>view1</default-activity>
        <view id="view1">
            <page>/view1.jsff</page>
        </view>
        <view id="view2">
            <page>/view2.jsff</page>
        </view>
        <control-flow-rule>
            <from-activity-id>view1</from-activity-id>
            <control-flow-case>
                <from-outcome>openView2</from-outcome>
                <to-activity-id>view2</to-activity-id>
            </control-flow-case>
        </control-flow-rule>
        <control-flow-rule>
            <from-activity-id>view2</from-activity-id>
            <control-flow-case>
                <from-outcome>openView1</from-outcome>
                <to-activity-id>view1</to-activity-id>
            </control-flow-case>
        </control-flow-rule>
        <use-page-fragments/>
    </task-flow-definition>
</adfc-config>
```

Main JSPX file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <f:view>
        <af:document id="d1">
            <af:form id="f1">
                <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
                    <f:facet name="center">

                    <af:region value="#{bindings.mainTab.regionModel}"
                        id="r1" />
                    </f:facet>
                </af:panelStretchLayout>
            </af:form>
        </af:document>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

First View `view1.jsff`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
        <f:facet name="center">

            <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical" id="p1">
                <af:outputText id="o1" value="Hello View 1"></af:outputText>
                <af:button id="b1" text="Load View 2" action="openview2"></af:button>
            </af:panelGroupLayout>

        </f:facet>
    </af:panelStretchLayout>
</jsp:root>
```

Second View `view2.jsff`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
        <f:facet name="center">
            <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical" id="p1">
                <af:outputText id="o1" value="Hello View 2"></af:outputText>
                <af:button id="b1" text="Load View 1" action="openview1"></af:button>
            </af:panelGroupLayout>
        </f:facet>
    </af:panelStretchLayout>
</jsp:root>
```

When run the JSPX file  **Hello View 1** and the button **Load View 2** appears, but clicking on the button nothing happens

I am also getting this warning at `action="openview1"`

> The action value does not match a navigation case outcome

I tried the auto completion goto in eclipse with `action="view1"`
still the button does nothing

Comment: There is a typo in your JSFF code the `action="openview1"` is should be `action="openView1"` ........`V` caps. Similarly `action="openView2"`

Comment: Oh my god I didn't see that coming, it is simply a typo :(